# Mysql multiple rows with a value that has a specific value in 2 or rows and which has another status

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

I have a table 'Item_status_history' with Item id, Status and created_at and associated order_id. This table holds an history of status an item has gone through.

I am trying to query all item_id which have multiple status = "Shipped".
and there must be at least one shipped status after a "Returned".

In the picture we can see the first set and the third set are the desired item_id I need.
The fourth set of data has 2 shipped but they were before "returned".
Note that the statuses are not ordered by created_at. I need to check if there is a shipped status after the return status was sent.

I have tried a few things. I tried to select all the item_id and its id with status shipped and use this in a subquery to again find status with shipped but not equal to the same id. THis is not working

```
select item_id from item_status_history as ISH where ISH.status = "Shipped" and ISH.item_id in (Select
        item_id
    from item_status_history
    Where status = "Shipped" and item_status_history.id <> ISH.id
)
```

This i know is only a part of it, then I need to find from the resulting ids, which ones have returned and if it is after the shipped.

Please refer the image below
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It must be some unique order of rows , maybe some ID ?
But we can assume, than if `Shipped` and `Retured` is in the same time, than condition about `Shipped` after `Returned` is fulfilled .

```
select item_id, 
   count(case when status='Shipped' then 1 end) number_of_shippments,
   max(case when status='Shipped' then created_at end) max_shiped,
   max(case when status='Returned' then created_at end) max_returned
   from item_status_history 
group by item_id
having 
   count(case when status='Shipped' then 1 end) > 1
   and 
   max(case when status='Shipped' then created_at end) >= 
   max(case when status='Returned' then created_at end)
```